# PHP webdrivers tests run fine from command line but only partially when build started by jenkins

Tags: php, selenium, jenkins, webdriver

**Software versions:**
jenkins version 1.478
selenium standalone version 2.25
chrome driver version 
Chrome version 21
PHPunit 3.6.10 
PHP webdriver bindings http://code.google.com/p/php-webdriver-bindings/
Ubuntu 11.10 using the GUI

**Summary:** 
In a new terminal window I run: 
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chrome_driver

PHPUnit/webdriver tests run fine when run as part of ant PHPunit task.
Chrome apprears, pages load, clicks happen etc. Browser is closed on tearDown().

However when jenkins runs the ant phpunit build task. The following occurs.
Chrome browser opens. Firs webpage appears, send keys works, form submitted. But browser window does not appear to close. It hangs. 
The jenkins build hangs indefinitely. I need to kill the build.

Any ideas as to why the selenium tests work on the commandline but not from Jenkins?

thanks
Jamie

UPDATE: it appears that a webdriver click. Selenium stops/hangs and accepts no more commands.

I.E.

$element = $this->webdriver->findElementBy(LocatorStrategy::xpath, "/html/body/div[5]/div[3]/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a");
$element->click();

//below this line is not executed.
$element2 = $this->webdriver->findElementBy(LocatorStrategy::xpath, "/html/body/div[5]/div[10]/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a");
$element2->click();

UPDATE 2:
I've replace the PHP webdriver binding with this one:

https://github.com/Element-34/php-webdrivergs with this version:

Some progress. Test webdriver/phpunits tests execute, and complete. However the jenkins PHPUnit build step still hangs forever.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried webdriver.quit() method?

Comment: I'm use the PHP webdriver bindings and the method to end a selenium session is called close. Looking what happens in there, php webdriver sends a DELETE request with the session to selenium. Works fine is I run phpunit on the command line.